# How to create a config file for a homebridge accessory

Tags: json, config, homekit

I have installed a plugin to control my Samsung TV (https://github.com/xeenon/homebridge-samsung-tv) via my Homebridge server, however the developer did not provide a config-sample.json, hence why I am trying to make my own. I am entirely new to coding so please tell me what I am doing wrong.

This is the part of my config file for that accessory as of now (I will add the ip adress and mac adress later).

```
{
"bridge": {
    "name": "Homebridge",
    "username": "",
    "port": 4318,
    "pin": "031-45-154"
},
"accessories": [{
    "accessory": "samsungTv",
    "name": "samsungTvAccessory",
    "ip_address": "",
    "macAddress": "",
    "polling": "true",
    "pollingInterval": "1"
}]
}
```

When I am trying to start Homebridge I get the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
at new SamsungTvAccessory (usr/local/lib/node_modules/homebridge-samsung-tv-controller/index.js:76:10
```

If I however change the config file to

```
{
"bridge": {
    "name": "Homebridge",
    "username": "",
    "port": 4318,
    "pin": "031-45-154"
},
"accessories": [{
    "accessory": "samsungTv",
    "name": "samsungTvAccessory",
    "ip_address": "",
    "macAddress": "",
    "polling": "true",
    "pollingInterval": "1",
    "enabledInputs": "true"
}]
}
```

where I added

```
"enabledInputs": "true"
```

i get the error

```
TypeError: config.enabledInputs.forEach is not a function
at new SamsungTvAccessory (usr/local/lib/node_modules/homebridge-samsung-tv-controller/index.js:76:10
```

I would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try valid JSON ? Would tell you are missing brackets around, also from first lines of source it looks like. It should work like this

```
objectVar = {
    "accessory": "samsungTv",
    "name": "samsungTvAccessory",
    "ip_adress": "",
    "macAddress": "",
    "polling": "true",
    "pollingInterval": "1"
}
```

Or like this in case it you are using string somewhere: "{\"accessory\":\"samsungTv\",\"name\":\"samsungTvAccessory\",\"ip_adress\":\"\",\"macAddress\":\"\",\"polling\":\"true\",\"pollingInterval\":\"1\"}"

And then there are methods **JSON.stringify**(**objectVar** [, null, **indent**]) or **JSON.parse**(**string**) to convert to string or back. **Stringify** has also optional parameters - first is a replacer function and second indent if you want it people friendly formatted.